# DbLookUpComboBox Dropdown

Tags: delphi-2010

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1v3LN.png)DbLookUpComboBox  Not Working

Im starting a School project and very new in Delphi
I created a form with ADO, ADO connection and ADOQuery controls

I Added the DbLookUpComboBox control to the form
I also setup everything as explained through other guides.
When I run the program, the Combo Box get populated, and I can see all Items from the Access Database.
My Problem is it wont Allow me to select any of the listed Items.
Almost like the Items is disabled in the list 
Is there anything Im doing wrong or need to enable to allow me to select items from the combo box

I managed to get the dblookupCombobox to work selecting items using the up and down arrow keys . I s\cant select items using the mouse

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured it out eventually.
I only had to add another ADOQuery and Source.
Then Swop the List field key and datafield around